# Class "X" not found (autoloader with PHPUnit and composer)

Tags: php

I'm learning about namespaces and class autoloader in PHP, for this I'm using PHPUnit to register the autoload with phpunit.xml and placing the namespace in composer.json, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I get: class not found.

**My file structure:**

juan-searching

```
--src
------Index.php
------Car.php
--tests
------Test.php
--vendor
--composer.json
--phpunit.xml
```

**My composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "juan/searching",
    "description": "Searching",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Juan",
            "email": "juan@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Scraping\\": "src/"}
    },
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5"
    }
}
```

**My phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="/vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

        <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
            <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            </include>
            <exclude>
                <directory>./tests</directory>
                <directory>./vendor</directory>
            </exclude>
        </coverage>

</phpunit>
```

My class (in /src/Car.php):

```
<?php
namespace Scraping;
class Car {
    protected $placa;
    public function searching(string $placa): ?string {
        return "DATA SENT";
    }
}
```

My index.php (for instance class Car):

```
<?php
namespace Scraping;
use Scraping\Car;
$data = new Car();
$data = $data->searching("123456789");
print $data;
```

***Note:*** After adding autoload and the phpunit.xml I did composer update + composer dumpautoload, I have generated the autoload, but when starting the Index.php I get: "Class "Car" not found".

Thanks

**Solved:**

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
...
```

Comment: I don't see anything about running a test except the phpunit.xml. If you're not running phpunit, then that file isn't going to help you load the composer autoload. You'll need to include it yourself.

Comment: <?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$data = new ...